# How can I go to rolling back to a specific commit in git?

Tags: git

```
I done a git log --oneline
111123 my login
222222 logout
```

I´ve tried git checkout 111123

This roll back to a commit specific but when i done a git push doesn´t roll back with the changes that I would like.

have I delete local branch and create in a new branch one older version 
with git checkout [commit]?. 
How I come back to a older version and push the changes?.

Comment: `git checkout COMMIT; git branch -D BRANCH; git checkout -b BRANCH` However note that overwriting history on shared server may create severe problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest thing to do is not to overwrite the history, but rather to simply change the state of the repo so that it matches commit `111123`. To accomplish this, do the following, assuming you are working on `master`:

```
git checkout -b temp-branch 111123
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Reverting state to match commit 111123"
git checkout master
git merge temp-branch
git branch -d temp-branch
```

Then you can push safely, and are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

To add the previous answer, I will do this using the `git reset <hash of commit>` command, this way you will keep the previous commits while you can safely go back to the desired commit.

Here are the docs for revert.
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

I will prefer this method since I see it more safely.

Answer (score 1):

After you do the `git checkout 111123` you are in detached mode. So you have to create another branch from that one with `git checkout -b newbranch`, and then you can do the push this way: `git push origin newbranch:remotenewbranch`.

Or you can remove the remote branch first and then push your local new branch made from the commit (`git push origin :remotebranch` and then `git push origin newbranch:remotebranch`), or you can do a forced update to a previous commit with `git push origin +111123:remotebranch`.